# Is it ok to pass interface of DTO to DAO

Tags: java, hibernate, dao, dto

It's about passing interface of DTO to DAO.

For example I have following code

```
public interface User {
  String getName();
}

public class SimpleUser implements User {
  protected String name;

  public SimpleUser(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }    
}

// Mapped by Hibernate
public class PersistentUser extends SimpleUser {

  private Long id;

  // Constructor

  // Getters for id and name

  // Setters for id and name
}
```

I'm using generic DAO. Is it ok if I create DAO with using interface User instead PersistentUser?

```
User user = new PersistentUser(name);
UserDao.create(user);
```

I read a lot of topics on stack but not figured out is this approach ok or no. Please help me. Maybe this is stupid and I can achive only problems.

**About separating beans.** 
I did this because some classes I want to share via API module, that can be used outside to create entities and pass them to my application. Because they uses interface I developed so I can pass them to my DAO for persisting.

Comment: Why would you use DTOs as interfaces and not as direct classes?

Comment: Because it can be useful when I want to store entity that comes outside with minimal changes. For example someone can have own implementation of User, and pass me only interface.

Comment: I still don't get your exact purpose. A principle in programming is YAGNI: You Ain't Gonna Need It. If you're not sure if this is useful or it can support a future change that it's not planned and probably not necessary to implement yet, then don't do it. And again, I still don't get your idea to use an interface as DTO. Use direct classes for DTOs for basic communication between your layers, use interfaces for specific cases (that I currently cannot found in your problem description).

Comment: Ok, maybe you right. What about if I want to hide setter methods of entity returned from DAO?

Comment: If you're not going to use setters in the DAO callers, then just don't call them there. I still don't find a good point on creating an interface just for getters.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I rethink a lot, and looks it will be hard refactoring. Last question for you how you think, can I extend my DTO from API class (PersistentUser from SimpleUser), or should I separate them and don't be afraid about duplication of fields? Thanks.

Comment: It will depend on your needs. If your needs are satisfied by using inheritance, then use it. If your needs are satisfied by separating the classes, then do it. I don't know your specific scenario and requirements, so it's hard to say what to specifically do here.

Comment: Also, you could have an abstract base class where the common fields are defined and the specific classes inherit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I would say it is ok, but there are a few hidden problems. A developer could cast the object down or access some state via a toString method that shouldn't be accessible. If you don't be careful, it could happen that state is serialized as JSON/XML in webservices that shouldn't be serialized. The list goes on.

I created [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage) for exactly that use case. You essentially define DTOs for JPA entities as interfaces and apply them on a query. It supports mapping nested DTOs, collection etc., essentially everything you'd expect and on top of that, it will improve your query performance as it will generate queries fetching just the data that you actually require for the DTOs.

The entity views for your example could look like this

```
@EntityView(PersistentUser.class)
interface User {
  String getName();
}
```

Querying could look like this

```
List<User> dtos = entityViewManager.applySetting(
  EntityViewSetting.create(User.class),
  criteriaBuilderFactory.create(em, PersistentUser.class)
).getResultList();
```